# ASUS notebook clock changing date on its own

Tags: laptop, bios, clock, asus-laptop

I have an ASUS K501U running Windows 10. From the get-go, it had issues with the clock. It would change the date on its own, regardless of using automatic time setting or not, or the time zone.
As far as I recall, it wouldn't happen during use, but only after sleeping / hibernating / restarting / turning off.
And it wouldn't change the time, only the date, typically a few days ahead.

I found several sources that mentioned that it was the BIOS battery which had to be replaced, but no conclusive information on the issue.

What is the solution?

PS: I have found also references to this same issue with other ASUS laptop models, a few years ago.

A few related links

http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/362404-windows-clock-regularly-changes-itself-random-date-time.html

[Windows 7 thinks that the UTC+1 Amsterdam time zone is really an UTC+10 time zone](https://superuser.com/questions/887117/windows-7-thinks-that-the-utc1-amsterdam-time-zone-is-really-an-utc10-time-zon/887123#887123)

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1731087/time-settings-changing.html

http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2012/10/are-you-having-issues-with-your-time-settings-in-windows-8/

https://www.avforums.com/threads/date-keeps-changing.1399372/

Comment: If you have the issues from the time you get it.. (and assuming it is still under warranty) - why not returning it back to ASUS?

Comment: How exactly does your day change? Is it always the same amount? Have you checked the time zone your PC is set to and also which time server it uses to sync time? Also are you sure it's not SkyNet growing in there and preparing plans for the future?

Comment: @Darius - That is an option, somewhat cumbersome. I use the laptop in a different country from that where I purchased it.

Comment: @Mario - *How exactly does your day change?* It jumps ahead a few days. *Is it always the same amount?* No. *Have you checked the time zone your PC is set to and also which time server it uses to sync time?* Yes, please check updated question. *Also are you sure it's not SkyNet growing in there and preparing plans for the future?* No, I am not. I will ask Arnold.